# Is it possible to create a method using these interfaces as parameters?

Tags: java, android, interface

I'm not sure how to word my issue so that it's clear. But I'll try my best sorry:

I have 4 interfaces:

```
        interface OnGetViewPagerListener {
            void onSuccessViewPager(Response<Feed> response);
            void onFailedViewPager();
        }

        interface OnNextPageViewPagerListener {
            void onSuccessViewPagerNextPage(Response<Feed> response);
            void onFailedViewPagerNextPage();
        }

        interface OnGetGridViewListener{
            void onSuccessGridView(Response<Feed> response);
            void onFailedGridView();
        }

        interface OnNextPageGridViewListener{
            void onSuccessGridViewNextPage(Response<Feed> response);
            void onFailedGridViewNextPage();
        }
```

And I'm implementing these interfaces into my class MainRepo. Inside each of these methods, contains a network call:

Main Repo Class

```
@Override
public void getPostsViewPager(OnGetViewPagerListener onGetViewPagerListener, String url) {

        //Network Call

        RetrofitInterfaces.IGetTop service = RetrofitClientInstance.getRetrofitInstance()
                .create(RetrofitInterfaces.IGetTop.class);
        Call<Feed> call = service.listRepos(url);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Feed>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<Feed> call, @NonNull Response<Feed> response) {
                onGetViewPagerListener.onSuccessViewPager(response);
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<Feed> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                onGetViewPagerListener.onFailedViewPager();
            }
        });
}
```

Is it possible to create a method with the networkcall, and with parameters where I could use any of the 4 interfaces?

```
private makeNetworkCall(interface canUseAnyOfThe4InterfacesHere, String url){
    //Network call
}
```

In case this is confusing, here is my code:

https://pastebin.com/y8kq9ZjQ

And as you can see, I don't want to have to type out each network call every time I use each interface.

Comment: private makeNetworkCall(interface canUseAnyOfThe4InterfacesHere, String url) -> this signature makes no sense, interface is not a DataType, it's a keyword. You could create a parent interface, have your interfaces extend it, and pass that type

Comment: @Stultuske of course it doesn't make sense. If they knew how to do that they wouldn't be asking. There's no need to point out syntax weirdness in a "what's the correct syntax to do this" type of question.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca there's also no point in posting code that will never compile and state: "this is what I want to do"

Comment: @Stultuske the actual question is "what should I put instead of `interface` in this method signature" but with bad wording

Comment: @jhamon which I also answered in my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My take on this:

These four interfaces are not needed. They are all the same interface:

```
interface BaseCallback {
    void onSuccess(Response<Feed> response);
    void onFail();
}
```

then your function:

```
void makeCall(BaseCallback callback, String url) {
    //do call and then callback.onSuccess
}
```

If you insist on different callbacks,

```
    interface OnGetViewPagerListener extends BaseCallback {
    }

    interface OnNextPageViewPagerListener extends BaseCallback {
    }

    interface OnGetGridViewListener extends BaseCallback {
    }

    interface OnNextPageGridViewListener extends BaseCallback {
    }
```

I do not think this is needed

Comment: ```BaseCallback``` may simply be a marker interface (without any method). That will then not necessitate any change in the existing interface definitions. However, they will need to be cast before being used.

Answer (score 0):

I think closed class hierarchy can meet your needs. [Here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html) more about it

Answer (score 0):

Apart from @Sharif ElKhatib's answer, which I think is the best way, another way is to write overloaded methods like this:

```
private makeNetworkCall( OnGetViewPagerListener ogvpl, String url){
    actualNetworkCaller(); //This has the actual logic of making the network call
}

private makeNetworkCall( OnNextPageViewPagerListener onpvl, String url){
    actualNetworkCaller(); //This has the actual logic of making the network call
}

// And methods for the other two interfaces

private void actualNetworkCaller(){
    //Network call
}
```